# How to display default Mail app icon in my own share sheet?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am creating a share sheet that I can fully customize outside of the native share sheet in iOS.
What would be the best way to have my UI display the default email app icon in iOS? In this example I have it as outlook, but It could potentially be Gmail, Mail, Spark, etc...any mail app that the user has set to their default.

Basically, is it possible to display the default mail app in the UI without pre-saving all possible app icons?
[Screenshot Share-sheet example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfDZR.png)

Thanks for looking- any keywords/documentation/help would be appreciated!

I tried setting default apps, but I cant find a function (if it exists) to initialize displaying a default app in Xcode

Comment: In iOS we call it `Share Extensions` You can read more here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/app_extension_support/supporting_suggestions_in_your_app_s_share_extension/